# How do I breakdown common elements in hash of arrays in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, intersection

I am trying to find any intersections of elements within a hash of arrays in Perl

For example

```
my %test = (
                  Lot1 => [ "A","B","C"],
                  Lot2 => [ "A","B","C"],
                  Lot3 => ["C"],
                  Lot4 => ["E","F"],
            );
```

The result I would be after is

- Lot1 and Lot2 have AB
- Lot1,Lot2 and Lot3 have C
- Lot4 has E and F.

I think this could be done with a recursive function that effectively moves its way through the arrays and if an intersection between two arrays is found it calls itself recursively with the intersection found and the next array. The stopping condition would be running out of arrays.

Once the function is exited I would have to iterate through the hash to get the arrays that contain these values.

Does this sound like a good approach? I have been struggling with the code, but was going to use [List::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Compare) to determine the intersection.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason why you linked to that specific version of List::Compare? If not, you can use https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Compare.

Comment: No there is no reason for linking to that version but it seems to be the same version you linked too? ' James E Keenan > List-Compare-0.53 '

Comment: Yes, it would be if you picked the newest. I meant "prefer metacpan over search.cpan.org as it always has the newest version and is more userfriendly" ;)

Comment: ok updated the link.

Comment: What about that _Lot1_ and _Lot2_ have _A_? It should group together as many as possible?

Comment: Lot1 and lot2 have A and B and C but im trying to break it down to intersections across as many arrays as possible so C is sepersted ar

Comment: I think you have to build all permutations of the lists. I have a partial solution without recursion that finds some of the intersactions, but not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done as two simple hash conversions:

- Build a hash that lists all of the lots each item is in
- Convert that to a hash that lists all *items* for each lot *combination*

Then just dump the last hash in a convenient form

This is the code.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my %test = (
    Lot1 => [ "A", "B", "C" ],
    Lot2 => [ "A", "B", "C" ],
    Lot3 => ["C"],
    Lot4 => [ "E", "F" ],
);

my %items;

for my $lot ( keys %test ) {
    for my $item ( @{ $test{$lot} } ) {
        push @{ $items{$item} }, $lot;
    }
}

my %lots;

for my $item ( keys %items ) {
    my $lots = join '!', sort @{ $items{$item} };
    push @{ $lots{$lots} }, $item;
}

for my $lots ( sort keys %lots ) {

    my @lots = split /!/, $lots;
    my $items = join '', @{ $lots{$lots} };

    $lots = join ', ', @lots;
    $lots =~ s/.*\K,/ and/;

    printf "%s %s %s\n", $lots, @lots > 1 ? 'have' : 'has', $items;
}
```

### output

```
Lot1 and Lot2 have AB
Lot1, Lot2 and Lot3 have C
Lot4 has EF
```

It generates an `%items` hash that looks like this

```
{
  A => ["Lot2", "Lot1"],
  B => ["Lot2", "Lot1"],
  C => ["Lot2", "Lot3", "Lot1"],
  E => ["Lot4"],
  F => ["Lot4"],
}
```

and from that a `%lots` hash that looks like this

```
{
  "Lot1!Lot2" => ["A", "B"],
  "Lot1!Lot2!Lot3" => ["C"],
  "Lot4" => ["E", "F"],
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Array::Utils` has an intersection operation where you can test the intersect of two arrays. But that's only the start point of what you're trying to do.

So I would be thinking that you need to first invert your lookup:

```
my %member_of;

foreach my $key ( keys %test ) { 
    foreach my $element  ( @{$test{$key}} ) { 
         push ( @{$member_of{$element}}, $key ); 
    }
}
print Dumper \%member_of;
```

Giving:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'A' => [
                   'Lot1',
                   'Lot2'
                 ],
          'F' => [
                   'Lot4'
                 ],
          'B' => [
                   'Lot1',
                   'Lot2'
                 ],
          'E' => [
                   'Lot4'
                 ],
          'C' => [
                   'Lot1',
                   'Lot2',
                   'Lot3'
                 ]
        };
```

Then collapse that, into a key set:

```
my %new_set;
foreach my $element ( keys %member_of ) {
    my $set = join( ",", @{ $member_of{$element} } );
    push( @{ $new_set{$set} }, $element );
}
print Dumper \%new_set;
```

Giving:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Lot1,Lot2,Lot3' => [
                                'C'
                              ],
          'Lot1,Lot2' => [
                           'A',
                           'B'
                         ],
          'Lot4' => [
                      'E',
                      'F'
                    ]
        };
```

So overall:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %test = (
    Lot1 => [ "A", "B", "C" ],
    Lot2 => [ "A", "B", "C" ],
    Lot3 => ["C"],
    Lot4 => [ "E", "F" ],
);

my %member_of;
foreach my $key ( sort keys %test ) {
    foreach my $element ( @{ $test{$key} } ) {
        push( @{ $member_of{$element} }, $key );
    }
}

my %new_set;
foreach my $element ( sort keys %member_of ) {
    my $set = join( ",", @{ $member_of{$element} } );
    push( @{ $new_set{$set} }, $element );
}

foreach my $set ( sort keys %new_set ) {
    print "$set contains: ", join( ",", @{ $new_set{$set} } ), "\n";
}
```

I don't think there's a more efficient way to tackle it, because you're comparing each array to each other array, and forming a new compound key out of it.

This gives you:

```
Lot1,Lot2 contains: A,B
Lot1,Lot2,Lot3 contains: C
Lot4 contains: E,F
```